# Updating Ruby Hash Values with Array Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I've created the following hash keys with values parsed from PDF into array:

```
columns = ["Sen", "P-Hire#", "Emp#", "DOH", "Last", "First"]
h = Hash[columns.map.with_index.to_h]
=> {"Sen"=>0, "P-Hire#"=>1, "Emp#"=>2, "DOH"=>3, "Last"=>4, "First"=>5}
```

Now I want to update the value of each key with 6 equivalent values from another parsed data array:

```
rows = list.text.scan(/^.+/)
row = rows[0].tr(',', '')
@data = row.split
=> ["2", "6", "239", "05/05/67", "Harp", "Erin"]
```

I can iterate over @data in the view and it will list each of the 6 values. When I try to do the same in the controller it sets the same value to each key:

```
data.each do |e|
  h.update(h){|key,v1| (e) }
end
=>
{"Sen"=>"Harper", "P-Hire#"=>"Harper", "Emp#"=>"Harper", "DOH"=>"Harper", "Last"=>"Harper", "First"=>"Harper"
```

So it's setting the value of each key to the last value of the looped array...

Comment: What do you want the resulting hash to look like?

Comment: FYI: `Hash[....to_h]` is redundant. You can drop the `Hash[]`, it's not doing anything, `columns.map.with_index.to_h` is giving you the value you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do:

```
h.keys.zip(@data).to_h
```

If the only purpose of `h` is as an interim step getting to the result, you can dispense with it and do:

```
columns.zip(@data).to_h
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help! Remarkably useful method. It's not listed in the online docs I was using so thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: This answer, imo, should have received the ✅.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I agree. It has been changed.

Comment: This worked by supplying a single object **row = rows[0].tr(',', '').split** but when trying to loop through them with rows.each, the .split method fails which in turn causes the zip().to_h to also fail. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Please submit a new question with a detailed explanation of the setup and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this problem but a more direct and straight forward way would be:

```
columns = ["Sen", "P-Hire#", "Emp#", "DOH", "Last", "First"]
...
@data = row.split

h = Hash.new
columns.each_with_index do |column, index|
 h[column] = @data[index]
end
```

Another way:

```
h.each do |key, index|
  h[key] = @data[index]
end
```

Like I said, there are several ways of solving the issue and the best is always going to depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ruby [convention](http://jeromedalbert.com/ruby-how-to-iterate-the-right-way/) is to avoid `each` (and indexes) when other methods can achieve the same result.

Comment: yes, you're right. But I'd rather also prefer explicitness over hidden abstractions

Comment: I'm all for explicitness, but how is `zip` more hidden or abstract than `index` or `each`? This seems to be precisely the use case for `zip` followed by `to_h`.